# Get type of template base class

Tags: c++, templates, inheritance

The next code works fine (this is a oversimplified version of other problem of mine, with types longer, deeper and more templates):

```
template<class C>
struct Base
{};

template<class C>
struct Derived : public Base<C>
{
   Derived() : Base<C>()
   {}
};
```

But, how could I call to the base class constructor without "write" the complete type of its base class? For example, I tried something like:

```
template<class C>
struct Base
{
   typedef Base base_type;
};

template<class C>
struct Derived : public Base<C>
{
   Derived() : base_type() {}
};

int main()
{
   Derived<void> b;
}
```

But "base_type" isn't recognized. The message that gcc throws is:

```
test3.cpp: In constructor 'Derived<C>::Derived()':
  test3.cpp:100:17: error: class 'Derived<C>' does not have any field
  named 'base_type'
```

To solve it I have to write `Base<C>::base_type` in the constructor but this would make the existence of `base_type` itself irrelevant.

Is it my campaign of writting-saving impossible?

And, why `base_type` in the constructor isn't found, and however this works fine?

```
int main()
{
   Derived<void>::base_type b;
}
```

**EDIT:** With the comment of [@Jack Aidley](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1502345/jack-aidley) the best form I've found to get the type of the base class with a simple alias is:

```
template<typename C> struct Base {};

template<typename C, typename Base>
struct Derived_impl : public Base
{
    Derived_impl() : Base()
    {}
};

template<typename C>
using Derived = Derived_impl<C, Base<C> >;

int main()
{
   Derived<void> b;
}
```

Comment: Any reason you can't do `template<class C, class Base> struct Derived : public Base<C>`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the standard

> When looking for the declaration of a name used in a template
>   definition, the usual lookup rules (3.4.1, 3.4.2) are used for
>   nondependent names. The lookup of names dependent on the template
>   parameters is postponed until the actual template argument is known
>   (14.6.2).

It means, that you have to tell to the compiler, that `base_type` in the `Base` class, that depends of `C`. You can use, for example, this:

```
template<class C>
struct Derived : public Base<C>
{
    using typename Base<C>::base_type;

    Derived() : base_type() {}
};
```

or this

```
template<class C>
struct Derived : public Base<C>
{
    Derived() : Derived<C>::base_type() {} 

    // or, as you already told, Base<C>::base_type()
};
```

Answer (score 2):

You can always do this:

```
template<class C>
struct Base
{
};

template<class C>
struct Derived : public Base<C>
{
   typedef Base<C> base_type;  // define here

   Derived() : base_type() {}
};
```

Makes sense if you will refer to the base type in `Derived`...